# Export SQL Data to an EXISTING Excel File (Specify Sheet)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The following code exports data to a excel file. It creates the file and creates a new sheet.

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append("SELECT * from dbo.PastAdjs");

```
 SQL.DataTable dtClients = new SQL.DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
                {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query.ToString(), cn))
                {
                    da.Fill(dtClients);
                    progressBar1.Value = 20;
                    textBox1.Text = "20%";

                }


                //Create Excel workbook for export
                Excel.Application oXL;
                Excel._Workbook workbook;
                Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

                oXL = new Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = false;

                workbook = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
                oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

                Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;


                int sheetamt = 4;
                for (int t = 1; t < sheetamt + 1; t++)
                {
                    newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oXL.Worksheets.Add();
                }

                int count = workbook.Worksheets.Count;


                Excel.Worksheet addedSheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing,
                workbook.Worksheets[count], Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                // creating Excel Application
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();



                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet1 = null;

              worksheet1 = workbook.Sheets[1];

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)worksheet1;

               worksheet1.Name = "PastAdjs";


                DataColumnCollection dcCollection = dtClients.Columns;
                for (int i = 1; i < dtClients.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
                {

                    for (int j = 1; j < dtClients.Columns.Count + 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 1)

                            worksheet1.Cells[i, j] = dcCollection[j - 1].ToString();

                        else

                            worksheet1.Cells[i, j] = dtClients.Rows[i - 1][j - 1].ToString();

                    }

                }


                oXL.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(filename);
                oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
                oXL.Quit();
```

How can I modify this to save to an existing worksheet in an existing excel file?

Comment: Just open the existing Excel file and remove the loop that adds sheets.  The rest of the code should be more-or-less the same.There are lots of examples of opening an existing sheet on the web.  FWIW, I use EPPlus rather than COM Interop for simple work with Excel sheets.  It's free, managed code and does not require Excel to be installed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366797/how-to-export-datatable-data-to-existing-excel-sheet-file